# how do I know that my in-app purchasing is working?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

This might seem like a stupid question (easy points for you all out there!), but I need to see if the in-app purchasing is working or not for a particular app. In iTunes Connect, I can see all kinds of analytics of premium apps sold and the free apps downloaded. But I can't find a way to filter out ONLY the in-app purchases made on the iTunes Connect dashboard. This is the only real way to find out whether it's working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clear the point. Do you want to test the inApp purchase on your app.like purchasing product with test user.Do  you want to do something like this ?

Comment: not exactly; the app is live, "out there", no longer in the sandbox environment. But actually in the app store. I just need to see using the dashboard analytics if the in-app purchasing is working with real buyers. thanks!!